# Conditional cases in Go select statement

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a select in Go that incorporates an optional timeout, something like this:

```
done := false

for !done {
    if timeout > 0 {
        select {
        case value := <- somechannel:
            // Do something with value
        case <- time.After(timeout):
            done = true
        }
    } else {
        select {
        case value := <- somechannel:
            // Do something with value
        default:
            done = true
        }
    }
}
```

That is, if nothing is pending on the channel, and I haven't set a timeout, I exit. If a timeout is set and nothing is available, then I wait for either the timeout or for something to be available on the channel. I'd love to combine this into a single select, but I can't see how I can do that. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need the second `select`? If `timeout` is `0`, the first will continue immediately.

Comment: Because if I combine all three cases into a single select, then it exits the loop immediately if nothing is available instead of waiting for something to become available or the timer to go off.

Comment: Don't combine them, just use the first select. The `time.After` becomes your default when timeout is 0.

Comment: Question on behavior: if timeout has occurred but there's still stuff on the channel, do you want it to exit (and ignore what's left on the channel), or do you want the timeout-exit to only occur if the input channel is also empty?  Also, If the former, is it important that the select _immediately_ exit on timeout, or simply within a few iterations (because select randomly selects from channel operations that are ready, so if timeout has happened _and_ the input channel has stuff, select could select either operation at random).

Comment: It would be fine for the loop to continue executing as long as there is content immediately available on the channel. The timeout only applies to cases where the select would block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement what you want:

```
func foo() {
    if timeout > 0 {
        timer := time.NewTimer(timeout)
        defer timer.Stop()

    wait:
        for {
            select {
            case value := <-somechannel:
                // Do something with value
            case <-timer.C:
                break wait
            }
        }
    } else {
    drain:
        for {
            select {
            case value := <-somechannel:
                // Do something with value
            default:
                break drain
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first loop is a normal consume until timeout. The second loop drains until there are no more immediately available.

Comment: Non-compilable (your `if` doesn't have an end bracket, and the `timer` declared in it wouldn't be accessible outside it anyway).  In addition, a nested select would work the same with less lines: https://play.golang.org/p/gA4VsToAl5.  Only breaks if the timeout has expired _and_ the input channel is empty.

Comment: It compiles fine (if you ignore the undefined vars). Your example could work and is nicer, but it ignores the timer as long as it is able to process more responses. My solution will finish processing whatever it is working on and exit after the timeout.

Comment: How is that different from yours?  Yours will continue until the timer hits, then will keep continuing until the input channel is empty.  Mine doesn't even check the timer unless the input channel is empty, but if it's empty and the timer has expired, exits immediately.  They have _identical behavior_.

Comment: Sorry for the unrelated comment but this `break` feels A LOT like a `GOTO`

Comment: @Kaedys FYI the playground does not run without `timeout` and `someChannel` definitions.